# Printing from the web with few steps

Tags: css, jakarta-ee, printing

I need to add functionality to my J2EE-based wep application:
1) Take some page, probably with form controls, convert it to some printer friendly format.
2) Print this rendered format a) without showing it and b) without a print dialog.

I'm not too worried about 1, but have no idea if 2a and 2b are even possible.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 2b is a function of the browser, not the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set a specific CSS print style. and just trust that your users can use their print screen button effectively. :)

here's an [article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html) from eric meyer on the subject

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start.  I'm not sure how this can be applied to form values, but I'll do some reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2b is going to be the real sticking point.  2a should be able to be accomplished with CSS via the "media" type...

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Print media style sheet that implements your printing requirements.
2. Print button in browser
3. Browser functionality that can do
   "quick print" to default printer.